# Cannot boot into recovery mode on Macbook Air with encrypted disk after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: grub2, 17.10, recovery-mode, macbook-air

I have a Macbook Air (2012 edition, I think) that I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on, successfully. I also have enabled encrypted LVM so that every time it boots, it asks for a password to decrypt the harddrive before going to the Ubuntu boot screen.

Now I've upgraded from 16.04 -> 17.10. However, once it goes past the decryption screen and into the login screen, the keyboard / mouse does not respond so I cannot log into my account. Per this [previously asked question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966799/ubuntu-17-10-keyboard-not-working-after-login-following-upgrade-from-17-04-gnom), I am trying to get into the recovery mode or some sort of admin mode so I can remove fwupd. Here are the things I tried to do:

1. Holding (left / right) <kbd>shift</kbd> while it boots, **before, and after the disk decryption prompt**. Neither <kbd>shift</kbd> keys got me into the grub screen...it just goes right into the Ubuntu login screen where my keyboard / mouse are completely disabled and I have to power down the machine physically.
2. I then created a USB boot disk with Ubuntu 17.10, plugged it in, and pressed <kbd>option</kbd> to get the Mac to boot from the USB boot disk. That got me into the USB boot disks's grub screen, but there isn't an option to get into the recovery mode or admin session of the Ubuntu OS that's installed on the **hard disk** (not the USB boot stick). In that grub menu I even tried the **grub** shell but as far as I am able to Google, there isn't a way to run "sudo apt remove fwupd".

Am I missing something? Is there another key combination I should press or something I can do with the USB boot stick?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out: at the moment you start the laptop power, keep pressing the ESC button. It'll lead to the grub menu where you can navigate to "Advanced Ubuntu Options" and then select the recovery mode.