# Ubuntu 17.10 keyboard doesn't work on MacBook Air even after removing fwupd

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, login-screen, fwupd

I have a MacBook Air which I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and then upgraded to 17.10 (Gnome version) last week. However, since the upgrade, at the login screen the keyboard and trackpad does not work and I cannot log in. [Per the previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966799/ubuntu-17-10-keyboard-not-working-after-login-following-upgrade-from-17-04-gnom), I have tried removing `fwupd`, but it doesn't work...

I know the keyboard / trackpad should physically work because when plugging in a USB stick to "try" Ubuntu 17.10, it boots into the graphical interface and lets me use the keyboard / trackpad just fine.

Any ideas how to trouble shoot? Searching / Googling have not yielded potential solutions.