# ubuntu 17.10 stuck at login screen

Tags: 17.10

Ubuntu 17.10 stuck at login screen ( mouse cursor not moving ) and keybord is also not working , after upgrading from ubuntu LTS 16.04 , Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should go to recovery mode using Shift after the BIOS.
And then try this:
[Ubuntu 17.10 Keyboard not working after login following upgrade from 17.04 (Gnome version)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966799/ubuntu-17-10-keyboard-not-working-after-login-following-upgrade-from-17-04-gnom)