# After upgrade to 23.04 keyboard no longer works under gnome

Tags: gnome, upgrade, keyboard

After upgrading to 23.04 the keyboard of my [GPD Pocket 3](https://gpd.hk/gpdpocket3) is not recognized on Ubuntu after logging into Gnome (I use [SSDM](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/) for logging in). This is the case under Wayland and xorg.
However, it is recognized under KDE (at least under xorg.

I do not think [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274890/ubuntu-20-04-keyboard-not-working) is related, as Kubuntu runs with the same Kernel. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966799/ubuntu-17-10-keyboard-not-working-after-login-following-upgrade-from-17-04-gnom) sounds similar but it relates to a rather dated bug that has since been fixed.

```
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type
```

returns 10 (Notebook) which sounds correct to me (this of course is under KDE)